# Mosquitto broker not validating username and password sent by the publisher or subscriber

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto

I have creating file named passwd.txt using the mosquitto_passwd and I set in the configuration file :

```
allow_anonymous  false
password_file c:/mosquitto/passwd.txt
```

But the problem is, the client still able to connect through any username and password.

what should I do ?

Comment: [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58663144/edit) the question to include the mosquitto.conf file you are using and the output from mosquitto when it starts up (this shows which config file it is actually using)

Comment: Also the path separator should probably be \ on windows not /